# What's the point of a MSc if I can just enroll in a PhD program?

Tags: phd, research-process, masters, computer-science, undergraduate

I am thinking about doing a PhD as I am quite interested in research, I really enjoy trying to figure problems out myself and having to find and understand the necessary information I need for my next report or project myself. This is great.

I am currently enrolled on BSc Computer Science and I am in my last year. Its going nicely so far. So long as I do well (at least a 2.1) then I will consider perusing a PhD.

The problem I have is that I don't know whether or not I should go for a MSc first before getting a PhD. I mean whats the point if I can just enroll on a PhD immediately?

I have talked to some other students who have done MSc/PhDs in their respective degrees and a lot of them tell me that I shouldn't waste a year of my life on an MSc, they say if your going to do a PhD, then an MSc is pretty pointless.

Is there truth to this?

Comment: This depends on your locale. It sounds like you are in the US. In Germany, you will usually need to have a M.Sc. to be eligible for entering a Ph.D. program. (Which will then not take as long as a US Ph.D. program.)

Comment: Dan is obviously in the UK - I don't think American unis give 2.1 degrees.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know you're going to continue on to a PhD, then there is no need to pick up a MSc, unless a specific program you're interested in requires you to acquire the MSc before continuing on to a PhD.

Some people want to have the flexibility that comes with acquiring a MSc, but this is a matter of personal interest, rather than a requirement. The danger is, of course, that if you decide to stop your PhD studies, then you run the risk of having worked for several years without any degree at all.

Comment: The "danger" you mention may not exist in all programs. In many PhD programs, you can be awarded a masters degree after completing the first couple years of the program (which involves work similar to a masters).